# Power BI matrix with added columns

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I want to create a matrix in Power BI with the latest keyword ranks, with also 2 custom columns with the latest *SearchVolume* and latest *Landingpage*.

I have a table looking like this:

```
Keyword|Searchvolume|Date|Rank|Landingpage
```

And created a matrix with the last 4 weeks to look like this:

```
Keyword|Week 1|Week 2|Week 3|Week 4
```

I want to add 2 columns with only the latest searchvolume and landingpage

```
Keyword|Searchvolume|Week 1|Week 2|Week 3|Week 4|Landingpage
```

I've tried searching how to add a column to a matrix.
I tried to convert the matrix to a table, but so far I haven't been able to figure out either option.
Also tried making it in a table, but i haven't been able to always get the latest 4 weeks as columns with   the rankings of that week. I haven't been able to succeed in getting the latest *SearchVolume* or *Landingpage*.

Comment: Much easier approach is to use a matrix and a table which you let run in sync with each other, based on keyword. Result for end user is same and it allows you also to enhance your report.

Comment: from what I understand, you have different column for each week. If yes, you'll have to unpivot our columns and use the unpivoted data in your matrix

Comment: @Aldert If I understand you correctly, I can't just sync the data, because the data is so much, you have to scroll down, which will cause the data in the rows to belong to different keywords.

Comment: How you normally work as a user, you scroll down the matrix and you see data what interest you. you click on that row and the landingpage is shown in the table (gives focus). If you do not want this, you will need to create a new table with all combined data (doable).